# ContentInset of UITableView, Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my app I have a view controller and it has a tableview as subview. Bellow navigation bar I have two subviews (with the total height of 85 px).
The problem is that the part of table view is covered by these views.

[image]

I have set the contentInset of tableview in viewDidLoad, however it does not solve the problem. Here is my code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame, style: .plain)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.register(OrderCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: orderCell)
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none

        tableView.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(85, 0, 0, 0)
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(85, 0, 0, 0)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    setupMenuBar()
    setupStatusView()
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try changing contentOffset of table view instead of contentInset.

Comment: Thanks! It solves the problem